# Django: convert all values of two clumn to absolute value

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, query-performance

Lets say, I have a product model with two columns, `price`, `sold`. I want to convert all the values to absolute value for these two columns and save it. Currently I do this

```
for obj in Product.objects.all():
        obj.price = abs(obj.price)
        obj.sold = abs(obj.sold)
Product.objects.bulk_update(all_obj, ['price', 'sold'])
```

Although this works, but this takes too long for a table where we can have half a million records. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can make use of the [**`Abs`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#abs):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Abs

Product.objects.update(price=Abs('price'), sold=Abs('sold'))
```

This will do the processing at the database level, not at the Django/Python level, so it will make a query that looks like:

```
UPDATE product
SET price=ABS(price), sold=ABS(sold)
```

Comment: this is a better answer. didn't realize `Abs` could be used in an update, for some reason I thought it was for query filtering and annotations only

Answer (score 1):

should be able to just use an F expression if you want to operate on every record:

```
from django.db.models import F

Product.objects.update(price=abs(F('price')), sold=abs(F('sold')))
```

other answer using `Abs` is more efficient, but will leave this here as `F` is a more general purpose tool for referencing model fields in queries and updates that is very useful when developing with Django.

Answer (score 1):

You use `F` expressions to get the fields and set the abs value for all rows:

```
from django.db.models import F
Product.objects.all().update(price = abs(F('price')), sold = abs(F('sold'))
```

See the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model